# Looking for "find a design pattern for a problem" questions

Tags: design-patterns, design-principles

In a job interview I was asked find a design pattern for the problem. I'm looking for these  types of questions with answers. Do you any resource like this?

Answer (score 0):

A book like [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) is essentially a catalog of design patterns (note that it's the seminal book on the topic, and many other patterns have been identified since it came out).

Any such book on the topic would help you; there are also online resources you could easily search for.

Probably the more important thing to consider is why an employer might ask such a question.  Are they looking for OO experience?  Is this a skill you bring to the table?